# JSTL tags don't evaluate if I import

Tags: jstl

I use dynamic include on a page:

```
<div class="top">
<jsp:include page="Header.jsp"/>
</div>
```

This is the important part in the Header.jsp:

```
<H4>
JSTL TAG Test: </br>
  <c:if  test="${sessionScope.username != null}" >
  <c:out value="Hello, ${sessionScope.username}"/>  
</c:if>
</h4>
```

The result on my main page source is:

```
<H4>
JSTL TAG Test: </br>
  <c:if  test=Swank != null >
  <c:out value="Hello, Swank"/> 
</c:if>
</h4>
```

I use this: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> in the main page.

Does anybody know how can I use JSTL if I import it from another page?

Thanks, Zoltán

Answer (score 1):

Add the same declaration

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

into your `Header.jsp` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by using **JSP include directive**

```
 <%@ include file="Header.jsp" %>
```

Because the content of the file given in the include directive is `pasted` as it is, in the place where the JSP include directive is used.

But in **include action** `<jsp:include>` At runtime, the included file will be ‘executed’ and the result content will be included with the soure JSP page.

---

**Updated:**

In JSTL condition should be written inside double quotes.

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.username} != null"></c:if>
```

Add double quotes in your condition.

Comment: I tried this:

<%@include file="Header.jsp" %>

But the TomCat throws an error page:

"message /registration.jsp(11,1) /Header.jsp(10,13) quote symbol expected

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /registration.jsp(11,1) /Header.jsp(10,13) quote symbol expected"

If I don't use JSTL in Header.jsp that include is working fine.

Comment: you are right, I made some modification on the code:

<c:if  test="${sessionScope.username != null}" >
  <c:out value="Hello, ${sessionScope.username}"/>  
</c:if>

But after an include the result is nearly same

Only this part changed:

  <c:if  test="true" >

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the given answer, just with a slight modification:

```
<@include file="Header.jsp" %>
```

Notice the '%' to close the directive.

Comment: Maybe you should open it with '%' as well. But it doen't work